# Are there layout qualifiers for different widget sizes on Android?

Tags: android, android-widget

So the guide [Supporting multiple screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for Android describes a bunch of qualifiers like `layout-land` for landscape mode and and `layout-w700dp` for screens with a minimum width of 700 dpi.

I am developing launch screen widgets. Are there qualifiers for different widget sizes? They range from 1x1 to 5x4 (or even larger). It would be a natural thing to see qualifiers like `layout-widget1x1` or `layout-widget3x3`. I can't seem to find anything to that.

If the answer is "no", how would you go about solving different layout for different sizes? I know I can easily manipulate single fields by subscribing to `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged`, ask for the current size and update things like font size based on that. But this is not feasible for larger layout changes like swapping a LineraLayout's orientation or content. That's where layout qualifiers shine.

Anyone?

Comment: "I can't seem to find anything to that" -- `res/xml-w700dp/` should work, to have a replacement widget metadata for that screen size or larger. Using dimension resources for `minWidth` and `minHeight` may also work. In that case, you would have one implementation of the widget metadata, but have different `res/values.../` directories with different `dimens.xml` files with the values for those dimensions for those screen sizes. Note that not all home screen launchers display in landscape.

Comment: I just tried `res/layout-w50dp`, which I believed should kick in when the widget is larger than 1x1, but that didn't happen. I think the qualifier is for screen size, not widget size

Comment: Correct. I was thinking that your concern was having different default widget sizes based on screen size. If your concern is having different layouts based on widget size (including user sizing), then I don't think resource qualifiers will help.